# How can I get test information with SonarQube API?

Tags: api, testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Now I'm trying to obtain test information with SonarQube API.
Concretely, I'd like to obtain information by using api/tests/list.(https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/tests)

My request url is:
http://localhost:9000/api/tests/list?key=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient&testFileId=5a3ed43a-5ae6-4154-a5bb-64c6134c69af
However, I got following reply:

{"paging":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":100,"total":0},"tests":[]}

I DID set the BROWSER permission, but still I couldn't correct reply.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the parameter `key` does not exist on this web service.

In your case I suppose that the value of `testFileId` is not a test file. That can be checked by calling http://localhost:9000/api/components/show?id=5a3ed43a-5ae6-4154-a5bb-64c6134c69af.

Example for the file HiveJobTest.java:

- view source: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/component/index?id=com.twitter.ambrose%3Aambrose-hive%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Ftwitter%2Fambrose%2Fhive%2FHiveJobTest.java
- get tests: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/tests/list?testFileId=2a792d03-aea2-4ef7-9c67-9ac06d99c5c3. If you prefer using key: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/tests/list?testFileKey=com.twitter.ambrose%3Aambrose-hive%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Ftwitter%2Fambrose%2Fhive%2FHiveJobTest.java
- get component detail: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/components/show?id=2a792d03-aea2-4ef7-9c67-9ac06d99c5c3. If you prefer using key: https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/components/show?key=com.twitter.ambrose%3Aambrose-hive%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Ftwitter%2Fambrose%2Fhive%2FHiveJobTest.java